# How can I plot data after cluster it into two cluster?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, clustering, plotting

I have some unlabeled data with 15 attributes and 30161 instances. I took 70% data for clustering and cluster those data into 2 cluster. I also added one column after clustering named 'cluster' and the column '<=50k' was label column. Now I need to plot those data except label column, How can I plot it ? 
Here's the sample of my code and data.

**Data**
[image]

`cols_x=train.columns[0:14]
cols_y = train.columns[14]
X = train[cols_x]
y = train[cols_y]`

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=10)`

`kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) 
train["cluster"] = kmeans.fit_predict(train[X_train.columns[0:14]])
train.head(10)`

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to plot, it depends on that also..

Comment: As I clustered those data into 2 cluster. So, I need to visualized those 2 clustered data with amount that how many data exist in cluster 1 and cluster 2.

Comment: You can do that using countplot on the target variable?

Answer (score 1):

KMeans on such data is meaningless if used carelessly. It looks as if your result is based on whether the ID is larger than 200000 or not.

Rather than copy and pasting example code from the internet now also to visualize, I think you should spend more time thinking about what you are actually computing. Because solving the wrong problem doesn't help.

Comment: Though I am new learner in python and clustering but I didn't just copy and pasting code from internet. And here ID is not larger than 200000, may be your mentioned column is `fnlwgt` and this data was for adults data, which I didn't mentioned it here. I think I have clear idea about what I need to do but I faced problem about plotting.

Comment: The column labeled `77516` determines your result. All other columns do not matter, except maybe `2174` when it isn't 0. Sorry, but it clearly looks as if you have *not* understood what function you optimize.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the first step could be to try to figure out how you could distinguish visually your two grouped elements (using colors maybe ?)

Hopefully you'll find some help here :
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-to-produce-a-pretty-plot-of-the-results-of-k-means-cluster-analysis

good luck !